# Implementing Instagram Login in React App

Tags: reactjs, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to implement Instagram Login in my React App. I am setting the `Client OAuth Redirect URL` to `http://localhost:3000` but the Developer account is not accepting the URL saying it has to be `https`.

Any suggestions on whats the best way to implement Instagram Login in React App

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this solution? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/

Comment: thanks I didn't know about this. Let me try this method out.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout these threads which discuss using `localhost` Redirect URI may be helpful
https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/1035796896617512/
https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/2324374700917110/

Also from https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/06/08/enforce-https-facebook-login/

> You will still be able to use HTTP with `localhost` addresses, but
> only while your app is still in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```js
HTTPS=true
```

in your **.env**

run app again `npm run start`